# Ruby: Delete a reoccurring hash in a large nested data structure

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash, nested

I am trying to move data between services and need to remove a reoccurring hash from a large record that contains both hashes and arrays.

The hash to remove from every section of the record is

```
    {
        "description": "simple identifier",
        "name": "id",
        "type": "id"
    },
```

Heres example data :

```
   {"stuff": { "defs": [
        {
            "description": "simple identifiery",
            "name": "id",
            "type": "id"
        },
        {
            "name": "aDate",
            "type": "date"
        },
        {
            "defs": [
                {
                    "description": "simple identifier",
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "id"
                },
                {
                    "case-sensitive": true,
                    "length": null,
                    "name": "Id",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "anotherDate",
                    "type": "dateTime"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "defs": [
                {
                    "description": "simple identifier",
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "id"
                },
```

...lots more....

I created a couple recursive function to remove the element(s) but I'm left with an empty hash '{}'.  I also tried to remove the parent but found that I removed the hashes parent and not the hash itself.

I'm pretty sure I could create a new hash and populate it with the data I want but there must be a way to do this.

I am not working in rails and would like to avoid using rails gems.

---

I figured this out by looking at the data structure closer.   The elements that need to be removed are always in an array so before recursing check if the hash key/value exists and delete if so.   I'm sure this could be coded better so let me know what you think.

```
def recursive_delete!(node, key, value)
  if node.is_a?(Array)                                                                                                                  
    node.delete_if { |elm| elm[key] == value }
    node.each do |elm|
      recursive_delete!(elm, key, value)
    end
  elsif node.is_a?(Hash)
    node.each_value do |v|
      recursive_delete!(v, key, value)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it would be useful if you posted the code you have written

Comment: You want to remove *all occurrences* of a given hash, or *all but the first occurrence*? And will it always be part of an array inside a hash? Are there any constraints at all regarding the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the way to delete the same hash as you have inside complex Array/Hash data structure, it's easy:

```
def remove_hash_from(source, hsh)
  return unless source.is_a?(Hash) || source.is_a?(Array)

  source.each do |*args|
    if args.last == hsh
      source.delete(args.first)
    elsif args.last.is_a?(Hash) || args.last.is_a?(Array)
      remove_hash_from(args.last, hsh)
    end
  end

  source
end

data = [
  {h: 'v',
   j: [{h: 'v'},
       {a: 'c'},
       8,
       'asdf']
  },
  asdf: {h: 'v', j: 'c'}
]

remove_hash_from(data, {h: 'v'})
# => [{:h=>"v", :j=>[{:a=>"c"}, 8, "asdf"]}, {:asdf=>{:h=>"v", :j=>"c"}}]
```

Possibly, you will need to adjust method above for your needs. But common idea is clear, I hope.